# Complex Analysis: Finding poles of a sum

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I find the poles and zeros of the following function?

$$f(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{\cos (z)-1}+\sin \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

In particular I'm having trouble with the function being separated by a sum and with $\sin (1/z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{e^z-1}{\cos(z)-1}$ has a pole at $0$ and $\sin\left(\frac1z\right)$ has an essential singularity there, $f$ has an essential singularity at $0$. Since $0$ is the only singularity of $f$, $f$ has no poles.